# Hour logging rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

I have a rails application built on top of the [Devise cancan bootstrap](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-bootstrap-devise-cancan) repo.

I have it so that is has all of the login and account functionality so that I have Admins (changing account privileges), manager (approve employees hours and make projects), and employees(log hours and see projects currently working on.)

What I am trying to do is make a page for employee's to log hours. I have set up a scaffold, and it generates a view with the form on that scaffold, but my question is how do I link to that page from the nav, and how can I make it so those logged hours are tied to that specific employee.

My scaffold is

```
rails g scaffold hours email:string day:date hours:integer
```

Comment: show the structure of your scaffold that you made for putting the times.

Comment: I added it, it would be nice to have it so isntead of having to put your email, it automatically uses the email you're logged in with, thats part of what im not sure about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you've declared the `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationships in the models, and that the hours model includes the `user_id` foreign key (`t.references :users` in the [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#special-helpers)), and that the relationship from user to hours is called `hours`, then you'd use something very close to this:

```
current_user.hours.create(params)
```

It starts with the `current_user` and traverses the [assocoiation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations), which causes the `user_id` to be set in the `User` record when you call `create`. `current_user` is the Devise method for access to the `User` object for whomever Devise thinks is logged in.

Comment: Im really new to rails and these libraries so honestly I did not understand what half of those things are, could you possibly expand a little more?

Comment: I can. Which is the first part that hangs you up?

Comment: Are the belongs_to and has_many relationships something that would already be set up if I have user accounts up and running?

Comment: No, you define these relationships in the models.

Comment: `class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
  
  scopify
end`

Comment: Thats whats in my role.rb file in my model

Comment: But in your case you want User to has_many :hours, and you want Hours to belongs_to :users (if that is the relationshsip - if the relationship includes the Project then you'll have to account for that somewhere too)

Comment: So for now, if I dont care about adding the project, how would I go about making those relationships?

Comment: BTW: I edited my answer to include links to the Ruby on Rails Guides for associations and migrations.

Comment: You would add the two method calls (belongs_to and has_many) to the Hour and User models, respectively, and you wold make sure that the hours table includes the user_id column (the foreign key).